# WordPress Inside Pages Default to Index Always?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I set up a site with WordPress using the automatic setup through a hosting provider. I am in WordPress, and it's working well in that I can create pages. However, when I go to view the page, it always defaults to the index page. So for example:

If I go to www.site.com/about
It goes to www.site.com

It does not show the inside pages. I cannot figure out why it is doing this. Any thoughts? I have set up new WordPress sites before and have not run into this problem. Did I miss a step in the set up process?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without putting my hands on your site it is difficult.  Is is possible for you to share a link to your site?

What theme are you using? Are you are using a custom theme? If so check if you have a file in your theme folder that is called page.php and that is not the same as your index file.

Try clicking on the page preview button from inside the page editor.  Check the url to be sure it is the one you are expecting.

Have you adjusted the permalinks in your WordPress configuration? Double check that it is valid.  Should be something like */%post_id%/%postname%/*

I hope some of that helped. try to give a little more info about you settings.

Comment: Thanks Samuel for your response. My link to the about page is: http://livoniasaveouryouth.org/about, and it defaults to http://livoniasaveouryouth.org. I'm using a custom theme base from http://starkerstheme.com/. My permalinks are /%category%/%postname%/

Comment: The pages are set to their appropriate page themes. I do have index.php and page.php. Should I remove one of these? These are not applied on the pages though in my site currently.

Comment: I just noticed that the index page is in the root of the web site folder. It's not the index.php in my themes folder. Hmmm.

Comment: in you theme  folder you should have both a index.php and a page.php.  when you are missing a particular theme template for instance in this case is page.php.  if any are missing the index.php is the default.

Comment: hmm when I click on your link I get the normal home page (correct) and  the other i get 
"About
This is a test page."
That looks right. What browser are you using? you may want to clear you cache and refresh your browser.

Comment: If that was the intended page and haven't really changed anything, then you have a problem outside of Wordpress.  I would highly recommend developing your site locally on WAMP or similar using Firefox with the caching turned off.  This will prevent your hosting from playing tricks on you with delayed file refreshes due to aggressive caching and possible proxy servers.

Comment: Thank you Samuel. You got it right, and my theme wasn't going through on the correct index.php page. This is why it wasn't picking up the page navigation. Such a silly mistake on my part, but it's something I managed to overlook. I appreciate your help so much, thank you!